# Creating table on ascx file with <% %> in foreach loop

Tags: web-part, datatable

I am trying to print out the elements from an arraylist in a table. But they don't show up in  tags. But they appear right up on the webpart title with a single line text.

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First Column</th>
            <th>Second Column</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <%

            lstTable = Data.DTable.Tablo();
            foreach (ETable temp in lstTable)
            {
        %>
        <tr>
            <td><%HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(temp.contact);%></td>
            <td><% HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(temp.companyName);%></td>
        </tr>
        <%}%>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First Column</th>
            <th>Second Column</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <%
            lstTable = Data.DTable.Tablo();
            foreach (ETable temp in lstTable)
            {
        %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= temp.contact %></td>
            <td><%= temp.companyName %></td>
        </tr>
        <%}%>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks but now I am getting some errors from the ascx.g.cs file such as  " Invalid expression term ')' ". I tried to clean the project but didn't work.

Comment: don't you have a separate acsx.cs file? the code file for the control?

Comment: Watch out for HTML and JS injection!! Use `<%: ... %>` instead of `<%= ... %>` in order to HTML-escape content.